# List Picker issue in windows phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone, listpicker

```
List<Items> list = new List<Items>();

        list = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
                   select new Items
                   {
                       Id = Convert.ToInt64(query.Element("Id").Value),
                       Name = query.Element("Name").Value,
                       title = query.Element("title").Value
                   }).ToList();

        listPicker1.DataContext = list;
```

Is it possible to show by default "Select" in windows phone list picker and whenever I select list picker item, the item should be display.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="listPicker1" FullModeHeader="Employee" SelectionChanged="ListPicker1_SelectionChanged" BorderThickness="0" Margin="130,-45,144,160" SelectedItem="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" Header="" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Height="55" Background="White">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22" Width="200" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Blue"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>



                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10" FontSize="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" Width="440"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" Width="440"/>
                </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>

    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>

</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this add a item named "select" and set it as default.

Comment: thanks bro for reply but my items source is coming from class, not manual,
it is binded with "{Binding}"

Comment: whatever may be the source,fetch it from your class and manage the states in your Object.

Comment: my list picker items come as a web service response, so how to solve?
thanks!

Comment: add it in your webservice!

Comment: I can't, because I have not created web service, I just call the method, it is created in java.

Comment: @VirajShah Please post the code where you generate your data